# Terminating because of 6 signal

Tags: c++, unix, gcc

I compiled and ran my code and got the following error:

```
Terminating because of 6 signal
```

What is signal 6 and what causes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably talking about signal 6, which is SIGABRT, i.e. abort. The code itself most likely called `abort()`, or perhaps an assert failed.

You can list the signal numbers from the command line using

```
kill -l
```

HTH.

Answer (score 5):

Signal 6 is usually SIGABRT.

One thing that causes that is the system call 'abort()'.

It appears your program also has a signal handler that catches SIGABRT and prints out the message, maybe like:

```
void handler(int signum)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Terminating because of %d signal\n", signum);
    exit(1);
}
```

You can also use the system functions 'kill()' or 'raise()' with SIGABRT (or 6) as the signal argument.  The signal could also be sent by another process.